# Error calculating the distance between values from a data.frame

Tags: r, geosphere

I'm trying to calculate the distance between different points that are a subset from a `data.frame`.

The method I try to use is `distHaversine` from library `geosphere`.
I have my data in var `st` and try using the function such as:

```
distHaversine(st[1,c(3,2)],st[2,c(3,2)])
```

Where each row in `st` is an entry of a new place, column 3 is longitude and column 2 is latitude.
Using the function in this manner gives me the following error:

```
Error in .pointsToMatrix(p1) * toRad : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Reading the error something like:

```
distHaversine(as.double(st[1,c(3,2)]),as.double(st[2,c(3,2)]))
```

sounds like it should solve the problem but that just gives med another error:

```
Error in .pointsToMatrix(p1) : latitude > 90
```

If I manually add the lat and long in to the function such as:

```
distHaversine(c(12.6959,60.3097),c(12.6959,60.3097))
```

It works and returns `0`.

The output of `st[1,c(3,2)]` and `st[2,c(3,2)]` is the following:

```
  longitude latitude
1   12.6959  60.3097

  longitude latitude
2   12.6959  60.3097
```

Output of `dput(st[1:2, 2:3])`:

```
structure(list(latitude = structure(c(422L, 422L), .Label = c(" latitude", 
"55.3376", "55.3836", "55.3838", "55.384", "55.3872", "55.4114", 
"55.441", "55.47411", "55.4889", "55.4907", "55.5", "55.5231", 
"55.5449", "55.597", "55.6048", "55.6049", "55.6093", "55.6333", 
"55.6402", "55.65", "55.6646", "55.693", "55.7", "55.7142", "55.7833", 
"55.8633", "55.8666", "55.8798", "55.9", "55.9033", "55.9081", 
"55.9245", "55.9557", "55.9833", "56.0131", "56.0133", "56.02391", 
"56.0304", "56.0419", "56.0431", "56.05", "56.0666", "56.0699", 
"56.07", "56.0752", "56.1333", "56.1498", "56.1813", "56.1957", 
"56.1977", "56.2", "56.2182", "56.2287", "56.2451", "56.2619", 
"56.2799", "56.2979", "56.3012", "56.3666", "56.38", "56.40404", 
"56.4495", "56.45", "56.4595", "56.4782", "56.5124", "56.5177", 
"56.5256", "56.5376", "56.5546", "56.5684", "56.601", "56.6166", 
"56.6333", "56.66694", "56.67", "56.6737", "56.675", "56.6784", 
"56.6833", "56.7154", "56.727", "56.7429", "56.7486", "56.7849", 
"56.823", "56.8311", "56.8403", "56.8427", "56.8464", "56.8526", 
"56.8666", "56.8865", "56.8994", "56.9213", "56.9222", "56.9252", 
"56.9303", "56.931", "56.9496", "56.9628", "56.9835", "57.0333", 
"57.0666", "57.0735", "57.1084", "57.1088", "57.1136", "57.11667458", 
"57.121", "57.1461", "57.1462", "57.1484", "57.1834", "57.1978", 
"57.2001", "57.2166", "57.2323", "57.2438", "57.253", "57.2577", 
"57.2674", "57.2833", "57.2847", "57.288", "57.2893", "57.3025", 
"57.304", "57.3672", "57.3689", "57.3848", "57.3908", "57.3915", 
"57.4034", "57.4042", "57.4166", "57.4208", "57.4413", "57.45", 
"57.4666", "57.4833", "57.485", "57.4983", "57.4998", "57.54361", 
"57.5571", "57.5653", "57.5666", "57.596", "57.6295", "57.6324", 
"57.636", "57.642", "57.6431", "57.6468", "57.661", "57.6614", 
"57.6678", "57.6687", "57.6898", "57.7071", "57.7084", "57.7166", 
"57.7213", "57.722", "57.7242", "57.75", "57.7514", "57.7611", 
"57.7666", "57.7786", "57.7848", "57.7865", "57.8052", "57.8232", 
"57.8305", "57.8425", "57.8429", "57.85", "57.8701", "57.8748", 
"57.8863", "57.8887", "57.8987", "57.9166", "57.9167", "57.93309233", 
"57.936", "57.9666", "58.0067", "58.0166", "58.0201", "58.03", 
"58.0333", "58.0389", "58.0492", "58.0582", "58.0718", "58.0729", 
"58.0788", "58.0794", "58.0908", "58.094", "58.0944", "58.0951", 
"58.1425", "58.1584", "58.1589", "58.19969", "58.19981831", "58.2", 
"58.2148", "58.2159", "58.2212", "58.2333", "58.2502", "58.2505", 
"58.2662", "58.288", "58.2886", "58.3", "58.3141", "58.3221", 
"58.3331352", "58.3333", "58.3339", "58.3476", "58.355", "58.3552", 
"58.3571", "58.37", "58.38", "58.3833", "58.3928", "58.3935", 
"58.3943", "58.3949", "58.4", "58.4004", "58.4072", "58.4166", 
"58.4274", "58.4358", "58.4397", "58.4447", "58.4529", "58.4666", 
"58.472", "58.5166", "58.5185", "58.5289", "58.5491", "58.55", 
"58.5586", "58.5707", "58.5719", "58.5763", "58.5833", "58.5842", 
"58.5929", "58.60033", "58.606", "58.6068", "58.6082", "58.6277", 
"58.6336", "58.6493", "58.65", "58.66076", "58.6777", "58.6894", 
"58.6998", "58.7104", "58.7136", "58.7165", "58.7333", "58.7421", 
"58.7433", "58.7588", "58.7833", "58.78468", "58.7904", "58.7906", 
"58.7936", "58.8", "58.8055", "58.8063", "58.8333", "58.85", 
"58.8509", "58.8772", "58.88", "58.8925", "58.898", "58.9", "58.904", 
"58.9333", "58.9334", "58.9502", "58.9671", "58.9733", "58.9817", 
"59.0185", "59.0297", "59.05", "59.0542", "59.0561", "59.0666", 
"59.0667", "59.0688", "59.08304351", "59.0833", "59.0966", "59.1166", 
"59.1412", "59.1469", "59.1547", "59.1789", "59.182", "59.1833", 
"59.2032", "59.2184", "59.2217", "59.2289", "59.2333", "59.2334", 
"59.2361", "59.2448", "59.2511", "59.2661", "59.2671", "59.2782", 
"59.2833", "59.2891", "59.2901", "59.2996", "59.3", "59.3107", 
"59.3226", "59.342", "59.3421", "59.35", "59.3537", "59.3582", 
"59.361", "59.3619", "59.3658", "59.3832", "59.3833", "59.384", 
"59.3867", "59.3868", "59.4", "59.402", "59.4166", "59.4428", 
"59.4445", "59.4446", "59.5052", "59.5171", "59.5345", "59.55", 
"59.5737", "59.5833", "59.5976", "59.6072", "59.6112", "59.6166", 
"59.6269", "59.6396", "59.6557", "59.6575", "59.6616", "59.6658", 
"59.6747", "59.6833", "59.7166", "59.7497", "59.75", "59.7506", 
"59.7534", "59.8085", "59.8139", "59.8321", "59.8333", "59.85", 
"59.8524", "59.8585", "59.8586", "59.8633", "59.8644", "59.8707", 
"59.8709", "59.88", "59.8953", "59.9045", "59.9098", "59.9268", 
"59.9445", "59.95", "60.0666", "60.0991", "60.1075", "60.1197", 
"60.12295", "60.1419", "60.1426", "60.1514", "60.1538", "60.1595", 
"60.169", "60.175", "60.2", "60.2026", "60.2357", "60.2363", 
"60.2688", "60.2761", "60.2788", "60.3", "60.3097", "60.3328", 
"60.3333", "60.3548", "60.3758", "60.3822", "60.4294", "60.4393", 
"60.4551", "60.4889", "60.5", "60.502", "60.5074", "60.5262", 
"60.5333", "60.542", "60.55", "60.6046", "60.6103", "60.619", 
"60.651", "60.6537", "60.6717", "60.6773", "60.7004", "60.7166", 
"60.7256", "60.7304", "60.7547", "60.75686", "60.8321", "60.88", 
"60.8846", "60.9066", "60.923", "60.9607", "60.962", "60.9645", 
"60.9676", "61.0025", "61.0442", "61.0666", "61.1269", "61.15829", 
"61.1666", "61.1691", "61.1766", "61.2542", "61.2555", "61.2691", 
"61.2797", "61.3198", "61.3613", "61.3784", "61.3882", "61.395", 
"61.4446", "61.5", "61.55", "61.6022", "61.6239", "61.6408", 
"61.6577", "61.6606", "61.6912", "61.7027", "61.7033", "61.7111", 
"61.7167", "61.7854", "61.8271", "61.8333", "61.85", "61.8526", 
"61.8547", "61.8691", "61.8892", "62.0166", "62.0291", "62.0424", 
"62.0471", "62.0943", "62.0991", "62.1132", "62.1299", "62.1809", 
"62.2207", "62.2314", "62.26317", "62.3809", "62.4066", "62.4112", 
"62.4172", "62.43064", "62.4502", "62.4943", "62.4961", "62.5", 
"62.5165", "62.5166", "62.5246", "62.5335", "62.5493", "62.5772", 
"62.6183", "62.628", "62.6431", "62.65", "62.72909", "62.7503", 
"62.7512", "62.7557", "62.7594", "62.76291", "62.8016", "62.8108", 
"62.8166", "62.8485", "62.9948", "63.0335", "63.044", "63.0447", 
"63.05", "63.0502", "63.0509", "63.0796", "63.1251", "63.1333", 
"63.1466", "63.1521", "63.1618", "63.16629", "63.1667", "63.1736", 
"63.1864", "63.1885", "63.1886", "63.1947", "63.1974", "63.2443", 
"63.2631", "63.2831", "63.3028", "63.30543", "63.3158", "63.3166", 
"63.3193", "63.3266", "63.3269", "63.37375", "63.3806", "63.4", 
"63.4119", "63.4304", "63.4359", "63.4608", "63.5739", "63.5949", 
"63.595", "63.6198", "63.6513", "63.6574", "63.677", "63.6849", 
"63.6968", "63.7", "63.73", "63.7606", "63.7695", "63.7788", 
"63.7947", "63.8082", "63.8129", "63.8302", "63.8395", "63.8548", 
"63.8683", "63.9187", "63.925", "63.9515", "63.9687", "63.9812", 
"63.9967", "64.0432", "64.0753", "64.0763", "64.0885", "64.1236", 
"64.159", "64.1661", "64.1973", "64.2", "64.2182", "64.2684", 
"64.2734", "64.3636", "64.4309", "64.43583", "64.4502", "64.4542", 
"64.4571", "64.4806", "64.4812", "64.503", "64.5057", "64.5059", 
"64.5492", "64.5666", "64.5669", "64.5809", "64.5871", "64.6244", 
"64.6389", "64.7166", "64.7306", "64.73431", "64.75", "64.7507", 
"64.7584", "64.7627", "64.8666", "64.9093", "64.9112", "64.9263", 
"64.95", "64.96782", "65.0074", "65.0106", "65.0251", "65.0333", 
"65.035", "65.0464", "65.062", "65.0706", "65.0942", "65.1049", 
"65.1089", "65.1317", "65.1522", "65.1808", "65.23", "65.2365", 
"65.2391", "65.25", "65.278", "65.2984", "65.3131", "65.3156", 
"65.3235", "65.328", "65.33", "65.3373", "65.4166", "65.5085", 
"65.53", "65.5354", "65.5374", "65.5434", "65.5592", "65.5762", 
"65.5953", "65.62", "65.6702", "65.6772", "65.68", "65.6935", 
"65.6982", "65.7", "65.7166", "65.7306", "65.75272", "65.7666", 
"65.7832", "65.7968", "65.8", "65.8077", "65.8151", "65.8211", 
"65.8249", "65.8333", "65.8367", "65.85", "65.8769", "65.8801", 
"65.8849", "65.8952", "65.9166", "65.9446", "65.9744", "65.9867", 
"66.0456", "66.0833", "66.1347", "66.263", "66.2801", "66.2833", 
"66.3002", "66.3006", "66.32417", "66.3824", "66.3855", "66.3862", 
"66.3888", "66.48", "66.48603", "66.499", "66.50502", "66.5333", 
"66.5343", "66.5759", "66.6135", "66.6235", "66.6798", "66.6815", 
"66.6932", "66.7265", "66.7374", "66.7529", "66.7586", "66.761", 
"66.7666", "66.8107", "66.8542", "66.8876", "66.8888", "67.0919", 
"67.1261", "67.1358", "67.1421", "67.1429", "67.1498", "67.1705", 
"67.2049", "67.2101", "67.2564", "67.3094", "67.3376", "67.3833", 
"67.3956", "67.4083", "67.4964", "67.5009", "67.6501", "67.6943", 
"67.7261", "67.7262", "67.7315", "67.7615", "67.827", "67.8488", 
"67.85", "67.8911", "67.9113", "67.9443", "68.04398", "68.0502", 
"68.0745", "68.2201", "68.2833", "68.3555", "68.3557", "68.4217", 
"68.4218", "68.4284", "68.4316", "68.4324", "68.4421", "68.4432", 
"68.6777", "68.6779"), class = "factor"), longitude = structure(c(81L, 
81L), .Label = c(" longitude", "11", "11.0062", "11.0333", "11.0685", 
"11.2", "11.2166", "11.2276", "11.3333", "11.3348", "11.41775", 
"11.5332", "11.5572", "11.5724", "11.6015", "11.6077", "11.6352", 
"11.6528", "11.7833", "11.8075", "11.8824", "11.9038", "11.9064", 
"11.92", "11.9321", "11.9333", "11.9541", "11.97", "11.9746", 
"11.9858", "11.9939", "12.038", "12.0387", "12.0542", "12.078", 
"12.1009", "12.1032", "12.107", "12.1246", "12.1253", "12.1454", 
"12.15406", "12.1563", "12.1581", "12.1761", "12.1833", "12.1997", 
"12.1999", "12.2223", "12.2689", "12.2741", "12.2775", "12.2963", 
"12.3024", "12.3153", "12.3166", "12.3292", "12.3579", "12.3616", 
"12.394", "12.4129", "12.41302", "12.454", "12.4798", "12.5438", 
"12.547", "12.55", "12.5514", "12.5521", "12.5843", "12.591", 
"12.6043", "12.6381", "12.647", "12.6491", "12.6702", "12.6739", 
"12.6775", "12.6906", "12.6928", "12.6959", "12.6969", "12.7", 
"12.7042", "12.7074", "12.7075", "12.7166", "12.7264", "12.7653", 
"12.77226", "12.7758", "12.8129", "12.8166", "12.819", "12.8203", 
"12.8226", "12.8332", "12.8333", "12.8441", "12.8538", "12.8542", 
"12.8568", "12.8575", "12.8705", "12.8709", "12.9242", "12.9247", 
"12.9333", "12.9359", "12.9414", "12.94361", "12.9493", "12.9834", 
"12.9841", "12.9843", "12.9908", "13.0164", "13.0166", "13.0338", 
"13.0406", "13.0595", "13.0607", "13.0625", "13.0666", "13.0667", 
"13.0668", "13.0731", "13.0734", "13.0746", "13.0817", "13.0833", 
"13.1", "13.1109", "13.11383", "13.1166", "13.1174", "13.1193", 
"13.1238", "13.1247", "13.1296", "13.1554", "13.1589", "13.16067", 
"13.1666", "13.1668", "13.18054263", "13.1865", "13.2152", "13.2166", 
"13.229", "13.2318", "13.2369", "13.25", "13.2517", "13.2534", 
"13.2593", "13.2666", "13.2833", "13.2841", "13.3157", "13.33", 
"13.3374", "13.3508", "13.3563", "13.3608", "13.3787", "13.3826", 
"13.3957", "13.3995", "13.4001", "13.4083", "13.4407", "13.4455", 
"13.45", "13.4666", "13.4728", "13.4833", "13.5037", "13.5168", 
"13.52", "13.5254", "13.5324", "13.5335", "13.5397", "13.55", 
"13.5609", "13.6115", "13.6191", "13.6333", "13.6488", "13.6671", 
"13.66833", "13.6689", "13.6748", "13.7058", "13.71", "13.7166", 
"13.7251", "13.75", "13.7529", "13.78495", "13.7975", "13.7995", 
"13.8019", "13.823", "13.8278", "13.8436", "13.8456", "13.85", 
"13.87671", "13.88040497", "13.8822", "13.8833", "13.8907", "13.8985", 
"13.9333", "13.9432", "13.948", "13.98", "13.986", "14.0375", 
"14.0383", "14.0476", "14.0733", "14.0842", "14.0921", "14.1", 
"14.1019", "14.10272", "14.1166", "14.1265", "14.1273", "14.1297", 
"14.1455", "14.1465", "14.1571", "14.1666", "14.17", "14.1831", 
"14.1833", "14.1847", "14.1859", "14.1947", "14.2", "14.2028", 
"14.2238", "14.2354", "14.25", "14.2595", "14.2666", "14.2833", 
"14.2874", "14.2896", "14.3166", "14.3172", "14.3188", "14.3508", 
"14.3578", "14.3678", "14.3692", "14.3786", "14.3903", "14.3951", 
"14.4", "14.401", "14.4086", "14.41", "14.4277", "14.4317", "14.4323", 
"14.45", "14.451", "14.4666", "14.4672", "14.4693", "14.4863", 
"14.4898", "14.507", "14.5085", "14.5126", "14.5535", "14.56389527", 
"14.5722", "14.5874", "14.6063", "14.6079", "14.6333", "14.6701", 
"14.6786", "14.6895", "14.6931", "14.7", "14.7166", "14.7333", 
"14.7342", "14.7571", "14.7908", "14.8015", "14.8024", "14.8176", 
"14.826", "14.8324", "14.8488", "14.85", "14.8517", "14.8744", 
"14.8833", "14.8881", "14.891", "14.8913", "14.8986", "14.8987", 
"14.9", "14.9019", "14.95", "14.9524", "14.9585", "14.97", "14.9853", 
"14.986", "14.9943", "14.9948", "15.0146", "15.0167", "15.0206", 
"15.03", "15.0455", "15.05", "15.0645", "15.0666", "15.0686", 
"15.0854", "15.0876", "15.0929", "15.0984", "15.1045", "15.1145", 
"15.12262", "15.1285", "15.1404", "15.1574", "15.164", "15.1694", 
"15.2", "15.2184", "15.231", "15.2352", "15.2359", "15.2365", 
"15.237", "15.25", "15.2544", "15.2553", "15.2686", "15.2742", 
"15.2747", "15.2833", "15.2854", "15.3263", "15.331", "15.3666", 
"15.3668", "15.3772", "15.37907", "15.3987", "15.418", "15.4324", 
"15.4372", "15.45", "15.4606", "15.4655", "15.47", "15.5", "15.5079", 
"15.5192", "15.5327", "15.5331", "15.5333", "15.5423", "15.55", 
"15.5555", "15.5561", "15.5725", "15.5857", "15.5894", "15.5921", 
"15.6235", "15.6332", "15.6333", "15.6603", "15.6666", "15.67093", 
"15.6762", "15.6833", "15.6858", "15.7", "15.7077", "15.7175", 
"15.7431", "15.7486", "15.7921", "15.8037", "15.8081", "15.8215", 
"15.8232", "15.8245", "15.8307", "15.8333", "15.8352", "15.8518", 
"15.8652", "15.9166", "15.9333", "15.9666", "15.9667", "15.9681", 
"15.98018143", "15.9833", "15.9883", "15.9909", "16.0017", "16.0353", 
"16.0581", "16.0833", "16.1088", "16.1137", "16.1166", "16.1212", 
"16.1333", "16.15", "16.15439", "16.1667", "16.1689", "16.1733", 
"16.1747", "16.1833", "16.1846", "16.2084", "16.2102", "16.2127", 
"16.21345182", "16.2149", "16.2166", "16.2283", "16.2383", "16.2388", 
"16.2662", "16.2774", "16.283", "16.2838", "16.2922", "16.2944", 
"16.3062", "16.3103", "16.3125", "16.3141", "16.35", "16.3511", 
"16.3666", "16.3667", "16.3709", "16.39", "16.3975", "16.401", 
"16.4036", "16.4142", "16.4145", "16.4149", "16.41734", "16.4199", 
"16.4295", "16.4311", "16.4549", "16.4585", "16.4609", "16.4631", 
"16.4647", "16.4648", "16.4683", "16.5333", "16.5358", "16.5393", 
"16.5418", "16.55", "16.5505", "16.5536", "16.5682", "16.5812", 
"16.5828", "16.5833", "16.6326", "16.6607", "16.6799", "16.68", 
"16.6833", "16.6875", "16.6919", "16.7114", "16.7337", "16.7387", 
"16.7462", "16.7896", "16.8157", "16.8421", "16.8536", "16.8723", 
"16.9166", "16.9168", "16.9531", "16.977", "16.9959", "17.0042", 
"17.0095", "17.0106", "17.0262", "17.044", "17.05", "17.0605", 
"17.0794", "17.086", "17.0879", "17.09442", "17.0967", "17.0983", 
"17.0986", "17.1008", "17.1121", "17.1223", "17.1536", "17.1641", 
"17.1693", "17.1748", "17.2", "17.2165", "17.2342", "17.2664", 
"17.2802", "17.2854", "17.3188", "17.3333", "17.3409", "17.3447", 
"17.3494", "17.3574", "17.40337", "17.4333", "17.4401", "17.441", 
"17.4498", "17.4666", "17.4704", "17.4711", "17.4718", "17.5166", 
"17.5225", "17.5244", "17.525", "17.5612", "17.5666", "17.5935", 
"17.6186", "17.6252", "17.6253", "17.6333", "17.6469", "17.65", 
"17.65431", "17.6623", "17.6666", "17.6677", "17.7034", "17.7085", 
"17.7166", "17.7426", "17.7478", "17.75", "17.7658", "17.86", 
"17.8671", "17.8716", "17.8833", "17.8974", "17.904", "17.9049", 
"17.9072", "17.9078", "17.9125", "17.9167", "17.93", "17.9462", 
"17.9471", "17.9513", "17.9545", "17.9623", "17.9972", "18.0159", 
"18.0179", "18.0234", "18.0575", "18.0577", "18.0592", "18.0618", 
"18.0929", "18.1", "18.1166", "18.1184", "18.1302", "18.1471", 
"18.1541", "18.1666", "18.1698", "18.1719", "18.1794", "18.2222", 
"18.2272", "18.2555", "18.2669", "18.2718", "18.2839", "18.2891", 
"18.2943", "18.3061", "18.3308", "18.3428", "18.3656", "18.3725", 
"18.3766", "18.3835", "18.3911", "18.419", "18.42533", "18.4333", 
"18.4493", "18.4639", "18.5297", "18.5318", "18.55", "18.5502", 
"18.5974", "18.6068", "18.6281", "18.6348", "18.6587", "18.6833", 
"18.7047", "18.7091", "18.7156", "18.7169", "18.7296", "18.7431", 
"18.7436", "18.8146", "18.8206", "18.8211", "18.8417", "18.8666", 
"18.9011", "18.9174", "18.9179", "18.9227", "18.9236", "18.9505", 
"18.9568", "18.9797", "18.9833", "18.9871", "19.0194", "19.0202", 
"19.0233", "19.0532", "19.0611", "19.0929", "19.1298", "19.1592", 
"19.1833", "19.197", "19.1975", "19.2", "19.2682", "19.3168", 
"19.3782", "19.4087", "19.4746", "19.4833", "19.4875", "19.4976", 
"19.5", "19.5058", "19.5059", "19.5666", "19.6314", "19.6673", 
"19.67495", "19.6768", "19.6983", "19.6986", "19.7123", "19.7243", 
"19.8316", "19.8392", "19.9", "20.02", "20.0993", "20.131", "20.1315", 
"20.1543", "20.2124", "20.2333", "20.2397", "20.2747", "20.2901", 
"20.2918", "20.3387", "20.3605", "20.4055", "20.424", "20.6333", 
"20.6455", "20.6586", "20.6686", "20.7565", "20.7652", "20.7891", 
"20.8144", "20.8692", "20.9", "20.9026", "20.9281", "20.9478", 
"20.9666", "20.97", "20.9858", "21.0537", "21.0558", "21.0662", 
"21.0717", "21.0846", "21.133", "21.15", "21.2263", "21.2666", 
"21.27997", "21.3152", "21.4907", "21.52", "21.5274", "21.5277", 
"21.55", "21.5655", "21.5666", "21.5787", "21.5791", "21.6098", 
"21.6167", "21.6317", "21.6335", "21.6396", "21.75496", "21.76498", 
"21.85", "21.9814", "22.109", "22.116", "22.1193", "22.1307", 
"22.2178", "22.2334", "22.336", "22.3518", "22.3666", "22.3753", 
"22.3961", "22.4488", "22.4502", "22.75", "22.8266", "22.8472", 
"22.85", "22.9001", "23.0571", "23.0924", "23.1005", "23.2", 
"23.3928", "23.3952", "23.4441", "23.4666", "23.468", "23.622", 
"24.113", "24.1162"), class = "factor")), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: With the data you posted I cannot reproduce the error. Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(st)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(st, 20))`. And start the script with `library(geosphere)`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas The output of `dput(st)` or `dput(head(st, 20))` is waaaay too long...

Comment: Then `dput(st[1:2, 2:3])`.

Comment: @JuliusVainora done

Comment: Step 1) `st[] <- lapply(st, droplevels)`.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan `as.numeric` instead of `as.double` is giving me the same error as `as.double`

Comment: @RuiBarradas "no applicable method for 'droplevels' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')""

Comment: OK, then that's step 2, step 1 would be `inx <- sapply(st, is.factor)`. Then `st[inx] <- lapply(st[inx], droplevels)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @IceCreamToucan said, the issue is that your latitude and longitude are factor variables. To fix that, you may use

```
df$latitude <- as.numeric(as.character(df$latitude))
df$longitude <- as.numeric(as.character(df$longitude))
distHaversine(df[1,], df[2,])
# [1] 0
```

What's also important is why this happened. In particular, we have

```
levels(df$latitude)
#  [1] " latitude"   "55.3376" ...
```

So, there must be a row with " latitude" as a value in the `latitude` column. As a result, when loading the data this variable became a factor. Similarly,

```
levels(df$longitude)
# [1] " longitude"  "11" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a wild guess that `st` is a matrix that includes textual data, therefore all data is coerced as `char`. try rebuilding your data object as `data.frame` (which allows multiple data types) and see if problem persists.

```
> st <- data.frame(name=c("A","B"), latitude = 12.6959, longitude = 60.3097)
> st
  name latitude longitude
1    A  12.6959   60.3097
2    B  12.6959   60.3097
> geosphere::distHaversine(st[1,c(3,2)],st[2,c(3,2)])
[1] 0
```

except for that I agree with everything @julius-vainora has written.